# Isolate Mono-specific code

Tags: c#, mono

I'm playing with adding Gtk# GUI to a Windows.Forms application. I need a way to isolate Mono-specific code in `Program.cs` since I'd like to avoid creation of a separate .sln/.csproj. In C/C++/Objective-C projects, I'd do something similar to `#ifdef __APPLE__` or `#ifdef _WIN32`.

C# appears to have the `#if` command.

What is the typical way to isolate Mono-specific code, or Visual Studio-specific code?

Comment: Please don't use #if, check this instead on how to make portable assemblies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721161/how-to-detect-which-net-runtime-is-being-used-ms-vs-mono

Comment: @skolima the OP wants to make a compile time decision, not a run-time decision. `#if` and `[ custom attributes ]` are the only way.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can define a symbol using `#define` and check against it, using `#if` and `#else`.

You can also pass the symbol to the compiler using the [`/define`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z.aspx) compiler option.

See the complete list of C# Preprocessor directives [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx).

```
#define MONO // Or pass in "/define MONO" to csc 

#if MONO
 //mono specific code
#else 
 //other code
#endif
```

---

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329043/how-can-i-conditionally-compile-my-c-for-mono-vs-microsoft-net/329072#329072) SO answer, the mono compiler defines a `__MonoCS__` symbol, so the following would work:

```
#if __MonoCS__
 //mono specific code
#else 
 //other code
#endif
```

---

The recommended method that the Mono "Porting to Windows" guide, as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/721194/1583) by [@Mystic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60892/mystic), is:

```
public static bool IsRunningOnMono ()
{
    return Type.GetType ("Mono.Runtime") != null;
}
```

This, of course, is a runtime check, versus the *compile time* checks above so may not work for your specific case.

Comment: Is there such a built-in directive that exists only on VS or only on Mono? I'm trying NOT to change the project file :-)

Comment: @Ivan - according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329043/how-can-i-conditionally-compile-my-c-for-mono-vs-microsoft-net/329072#329072) SO answer, it defines `__MonoCS__`.

Comment: I have no idea how you managed to find that, I took my time to find the answer and turned up nothing :-) I'll go the `Type.GetType()` route, mentioned in that answer. Thanks!

Comment: …except that would mean MSVC would still see references to GTK code. So `#if __MonoCS__` it is. Thanks again!

Comment: Downvoted. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721161/how-to-detect-which-net-runtime-is-being-used-ms-vs-mono is a much better way, as the same assembly will work on both platforms.

Comment: @skolima - Added details of linked answer. However, you need to consider that some use cases will require compile time resolution versus the runtime resolution detailed in the answer you linked to.

Comment: I still prefer to extract the platform specific code into a helper assembly and choose one or the other version during runtime. It's much less confusing for the user when there's only a single version to download/deploy.

Comment: @skolima - I am not arguing that your preference is not the better option, just that for _some_ use cases, determining this at runtime is not the right choice.