# Mono predefined macro?

Tags: c#, mono

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I conditionally compile my C# for Mono vs. Microsoft .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329043/how-can-i-conditionally-compile-my-c-sharp-for-mono-vs-microsoft-net)

I have sqlite in my project and I'd like to run it in mono. The code is exactly the same for mono and nonmono however mono needs me to include a different namespace. Does mono have a predefined macro? Right now i define USE_MONO. Is there an official definition i can use?

```
#if USE_MONO
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
#else
using System.Data.SQLite;
#endif
```

Comment: Yep, dupe. Lets close my question

Answer (score 1):

(From the [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329043/how-can-i-conditionally-compile-my-c-sharp-for-mono-vs-microsoft-net)) The mono compiler defines `__MonoCS__` for this purpose so you can use:

```
#if __MonoCS__
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
#else
using System.Data.SQLite;
#endif
```