# Does gmcs or xbuild predefine any properties?

Tags: mono, xbuild

I'm porting some .NET code to mono, which involves #if blocks like:

```
#if !MONO
// Stuff that only works in >NET
#endif
```

I can define these things in the csproj file and set a mono build target. However, I was wondering if xbuild or gmcs predefined anything  so I know if I'm compiling on mono.

Comment: [gmcs.exe defines __MonoCS__](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329043/how-can-i-conditionally-compile-my-c-sharp-for-mono-vs-microsoft-net/329072#329072). This is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no. There's no default flag.

For gmcs, use `gmcs -d:MONO`. If you build using xbuild, you can set the flag in the `.csproj`.